# Selenium Webdriver: Can i have mouse over action using href?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, href, mouseover

**My code**

```
class="dropdown-toggle doTransition ng-binding"
    ng-mouseenter="recentList(null,key,0)"
    ng-click="ga('send', 'event', 'Menu', 'Click', topNav.title);"
    href="/television">

class="dropdown-toggle doTransition ng-binding"
    ng-mouseenter="recentList(null,key,0)"
    ng-click="ga('send', 'event', 'Menu', 'Click', topNav.title);"
    href="/bollywood">
```

I want to have a mouse over action using href. Can anyone suggest me what can be done? Is XPath the only way you can find element?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cssSelector` to find the element and [Actions](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) to do the hovering

> C# code, syntax is similar in all languages

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[href*='television']"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.MoveToElement(element).Build().Perform();
```

`element` will be an web element witch contains "television" in its `href`

Answer (score 0):

> Is XPath the only way you can find element?

The `By` class shows you can find elements by:

- class name
- CSS selector
- `id` (attribute)
- link text (full or partial)
- `name` attribute
- HTML tag name
- XPath query